# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown while selecting data from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have two datatables, one contains more than 1,000,000 rows of data and the second one has 1,500,000 rows, and I'm filtering few data using datatable.select.

The first table (the one with 1,000,000 rows of data) generates an out of memory exception but the second, which has more than 1,500,000 rows, runs properly.

How could I fix it?

My code:

```
Dim row as DataRow=dt.select("UniqueID = " & "'" & Edgeid & "'").FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: i'm using given code to select the value from the datatable but this is throwing given exception

Comment: hi folks pls help me out

Comment: Is there any chance that you could use a separate database instead of an internal datatable?

Comment: Is UniqueID really a string?

Answer (score 0):

Filter on the server instead of on the client. You are loading the whole table over the network onto your client and then start filtering for a single record. Terribly bad idea. The reason why the bigger table works is because its *record size* is probably less:

For 1.5 million times 100 byte your memory might be just enough, for 1 million times 1000 bytes not.

So you write a query like this instead and only 1 record is transported (which is super fast, if UniqueID is indexed, and needs minimal memory).

```
$"SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE UniqueID = {Edgeid};" 'in case Edgeid is numerical or
$"SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE UniqueID = '{Edgeid}';" 'in case Edgeid is a string
```

Hope that helps.